# Concat two CSVs with different number of rows returning warning

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, concatenation

I need to concat two CSVs with a different number of rows. I receive a warning when I do so and the results in `print(df1.head())` return an empty dataframe when I know by visual inspection that there are matching rows.

Could the warning affect the results reflected in head()? Or is there another issue I need to resolve?

```
# columns to filter on
columns_to_match = ['column1', 'column2', 'column3', 'column4', 'column5']

# find matching rows based off columns in filter 
filter = df1[columns_to_match].eq(df2[columns_to_match]).all(axis=1)

# concat filtered results
df1 = pd.concat([df1[columns_to_match], df2[columns_to_match]])

# print matching results 
print(df1.head())
```

I receive the following error:

```
UserWarning: Boolean Series key will be reindexed to match DataFrame index.
df1 = pd.concat([df1[filter], df2[filter]])
```

Thank you.

Comment: You might need `df1[columns_to_match].append(df2[columns_to_match]).drop_duplicates()` or `pd.merge(df1, df2, on=columns_to_match)`

Comment: Thank you. I changed variable name from 'filter' to 'columns_to_match'. The results are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to [@ags29](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8671053/ags29) and [@not_speshal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9857631/not-speshal). Both of your suggestions led me to this solution.

```
# columns to filter on
columns_to_match = ['column1', 'column2', 'column3', 'column4', 'column5']

# merge filtered results)
df1 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=columns_to_match)

print(df1.head())
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you have multiple uses for `filter`, which is confusing and error-prone. I believe that the warning arises because `filter = df1[filter].eq(df2[filter]).all(axis=1)`  is a series aligned to `df1`. However you then try to subset `df2` using the same mask series.

One way to fix it would be to have e.g. `filter2 = df2[cols].eq(df1[cols]).all(axis=1)` and then do
`df1 = pd.concat([df1[filter], df2[filter2]])`

(note that I am defining `cols = ['column1', 'column2', 'column3', 'column4', 'column5']` here.

Edit - this should work:

```
# find matching rows based off columns in filter 
filter1 = df1[columns_to_match].eq(df2[columns_to_match]).all(axis=1)
filter2 = df2[columns_to_match].eq(df1[columns_to_match]).all(axis=1)

# concat filtered results
df1 = pd.concat([df1[filter1], df2[filter2]])
```

Comment: Are you still using the variable 'filter' in your solution or only the code after 'One way to fix it?' Thank you.

Comment: yes to keep things simple, retain `filter` as you defined it. The issue is `df2[filter]`, which should change to `df2[filter2]`.

Comment: I now need to declare filter after filter2 as we are using filter2 in filter. I am receiving the error: "TypeError: filter expected 2 arguments, got 1" from the filter declaration line. I have renamed the column list to 'cols'.

Comment: see edit, does that work?

Comment: Thank you. The code runs but I still receive the 'reindexed to match DataFrame index.' warning and an empty dataframe. This may be an indication that there is another issue.